# Trying to shape a section of a mesh to insert a 3d printed ball joint

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

I'm trying to make a ball joint model like this but with my own character.

[image: Reference Model]

https://www.thingiverse.com/make:489858

I have made the shape I want to cut out of it, but I've used multiple different methods from booleans to installing an "Auto Boolean" tool that will let me subtract the object from the mesh and I keep getting nasty edges. I don't know how to apply this shape (which has to be exact so the ball of the leg fits correctly) without getting this garbage mess.

[image: My model's mess]

On the left is a leg with the object subtracted, and to the right of that legs that have just been modeled with the shape ready to be removed from it. I just want to add ball joint sockets to my own model, I don't understand why it is so difficult to cut out this basic shape. Please help.

[image: I've put a lot of love into this character, I just don't know where to go from here.]

*(Here is the blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/au196k85u4h7kda/SharedModel.blend?dl=0
I want to learn how to do this right, not just get it done. I'm trying to give her feet ball joints. The model is on layer 1 (Her eyes are on layer 2- not sure how I'm going to combine them into one solid mesh yet but I think you need to do that to make a thing 3D printable.)

Layer 3 was the first template I made taken from the reference octopus. Since the reference has been printed already it looks like it works so I was going to start learning with that. However using this to boolean makes a mess.

Layer 4 is my attempt at taking a cut out. It looks horrible smoothed, but sort of ok flat?

Layer 5 is a leg separated from the body.

Layer 8 was my attempt at making a new template to cut a boolean out of using only quads.
The far far right upper layer is an octopus someone else made that uses ball joints for the legs. The body isn't the same though, my character is built differently, so I just wanted to copy the joint principle.
Everything should be labeled when you click on it.)*